# setTimeout(..0) ordering

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, settimeout

During studying JS, the following code is mysterious to me.

The following code never print out 'this is fn'?

I am not sure `fn=null;` is always called first before callback function of 
`setTimtout(..,0)`

```
function fn(){
    console.log('this is fn');
}

var intv = setTimeout( function(){ 
    intv = null;
    if (fn) fn();
}, 0 ); 

fn = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how JavaScript execute any function. The datastrcture is called as Call Stack

> Call Stack :- It’s a data structure which records the function calls, basically where in the program we are. If we call a function to
>   execute , we push something on to the stack, and when we return from a
>   function, we pop off the top of the stack.

Here in your case the complete script itself is first call we can call it main.

So first entry in stack is,

```
function fn(){
    console.log('this is fn');
}

var intv = setTimeout( function(){ 
    intv = null;
    if (fn) fn();
}, 0 ); 

fn = null;
```

In that code the set timeout is second call after the first entry executed.

```
var intv = setTimeout( function(){ 
        intv = null;
        if (fn) fn();
    }, 0 );
```

Now JavaScript call stack will execute the first entry which sets the value to fn to null at last line.

Then it will execute the timeout interval function where fn is null. Where if (fn) will return false and nothing will be executed at all.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is how it will work. The callback function of `setTimeout` will be pushed in the queue until the stack gets empty.

The stack will get empty after the assignment `fn = null;`.

Now the event loop will push the callback to stack as it will be empty and hence it will execute and as the `fn` is not a function anymore but null so will not do any `console.log`.

Answer (score 2):

A timeout will not run the function until:

- The timeout has passed
- The minimum timeout has passed
- The event loop isn't busy running some other code

So you:

1. Define a function
2. Define a timeout
3. Set `fm` to null

At this stage the event loop stops being busy.

If the minimum timeout hasn't passed, then JS waits a bit.

Then the function gets called.

`fn` is `null`.